# Adding an item to a generic List<T> with Reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

**Edit:** Move along please, nothing to see here.

*The solution to this question had nothing to do with Reflection and everything to do with me not paying attention to the implementation of the collection property in a base class.*

---

I'm trying to add an item to a collection using Reflection using the following method:

```
public void AddReferenceToCollection(object targetResource, string propertyName, object resourceToBeAdded)
{
    Type targetResourceType = targetResource.GetType();
    PropertyInfo collectionPropertyInfo = targetResourceType.GetProperty(propertyName);

    // This seems to get a copy of the collection property and not a reference to the actual property
    object collectionPropertyObject = collectionPropertyInfo.GetValue(targetResource, null);
    Type collectionPropertyType = collectionPropertyObject.GetType();
    MethodInfo addMethod = collectionPropertyType.GetMethod("Add");

    if (addMethod != null)
    {
        // The following works correctly (there is now one more item in the collection), but collectionPropertyObject.Count != targetResource.propertyName.Count
        collectionPropertyType.InvokeMember("Add", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, collectionPropertyObject, new[] { resourceToBeAdded });
    }
    else
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException(propertyName + " has no 'Add' method");
    }
}
```

However, it appears that the call to `targetResource.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(targetResource, null)` returns a copy of `targetResource.propertyName` and not a reference to it and so the subsequent call to `collectionPropertyType.InvokeMember` affects the copy and not the reference.

How can I add the `resourceToBeAdded` object to the `propertyName` collection property of the `targetResource` object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
public void AddReferenceToCollection(object targetResource, string propertyName, object resourceToBeAdded)
{
    var col = targetResource.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(targetResource, null) as IList;
    if(col != null)
        col.Add(resourceToBeAdded);
    else
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Not a list");
}
```

**Edit**: Test usage

```
void Main()
{

    var t = new Test();
    t.Items.Count.Dump(); //Gives 1
    AddReferenceToCollection(t, "Items", "testItem");
    t.Items.Count.Dump(); //Gives 2
}
public class Test
{
    public IList<string> Items { get; set; }

    public Test()
    {
        Items = new List<string>();
        Items.Add("ITem");
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's still not updating the `targetResource.propertyName` newly created one (targetResource.propertyName.Count != col.Count).

Comment: Hmm, yes it does. OK my mistake. Error between my seat and my keyboard.